# Add new elements in a div from HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP code, where i use an HTML code, all this look similar to the next fragment of code :

```
<?php
    $receiverNumber = 1;
    $senderNumber = 1;
?>

<head>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</head>
<form method="post" action="">
    <div id="senders">
        <div>
            Sender 0
            <input placeholder="Sender ID" name="sender-0"/>
            <button name="addSender">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="receivers">
        <div>
            Receiver 0
            <input placeholder="Receiver Wallet ID" name="receiver-0"/>
            <input placeholder="Received Sum" name="received-0"/>
            <button onClick="addNewElement('receivers', <?php $receiverNumber ?>, 'R')">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

What I want here to do is by clicking on `+` button is to trigger a function which will add a new element in the div. Here's the JS code which I'm using :

```
function newSender(ID){
    return (`<div>
                 Sender ${ID}
                <input placeholder="Sender ID" name="sender-${ID}"/>
            </div>`);
};
function newReceiver(ID){
    return (`<div>
                 Receiver ${ID}
                <input placeholder="Receiver Wallet ID" name="sender-${ID}"/>
                <input placeholder="Received Sum" name="received-${ID}"/>
            </div>`);
};
function addNewElement(id, idNum, purpose){
    switch(purpose){
        case 'R' : fragment = newReceiver(idNum); break;
        case 'S' : fragment = newSender(idNum); break;
        default: break;
    };
    element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.insertBefore(fragment, element.firstChild);
}
```

and, when I press on the button to which the function was assigned, the page just refreshes and doesn't display anything, what is the problem in this code?

Comment: In the button inside the form, just add type="button", if not , by default the button will trigger the submit action of the form, that's the reason why is reloading

Comment: Thanks, this solved half of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `appendChild()` method.

Also, you are missing the `type="button"` element in your HTML.

Change this: `<button name="addSender">+</button>` to this :`<type="button" button name="addSender">+</button>`

Comment: I'm trying now what you said about appendChild()

Comment: Let me know your results.

Comment: The idea with appendChild, that solved my problem, thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change your button type to `button` so it doesn't submit the form when you click it.

Then, `insertBefore` requires a node as its first parameter, so you can do this:

```
const fragmentElement = new DOMParser().parseFromString(fragment, 'text/html');    
element.insertBefore(fragmentElement.firstChild, element.firstChild);
```

Comment: below the element which I've assigned a function to, I have some more elements, and when I press on the button all the content below the div, & including the div is removed and the new element is added =/

Comment: This shouldn't happen. `insertBefore` only adds stuff, doesn't remove anything (it can also move the element you want to insert, if it already exists).

Answer (score 0):

why you doesn't use `append()` or `before()`,`after()` jQuery functions?
its most simply way to add elements inside another.
for example:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('ElementSelector').append('anyContent');
})
```

This will add any content `(html or text)` inside and at the end of `ElementSelector`

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('anyElementSelector').after('anyContent');
});

$('button').click(function(){
    $('anyElementSelector').before('anyContent');
});
```

This two functions will insert any content `(html or text)` after or before the `ElementSelector`

Comment: Why use JQuery? There is no existing JQuery in his code so that would take more time than its worth? Pure JS works just fine for this...what are your thoughts?

Comment: I saw  he is not using jquery but i suggest theses function because in my point of view it is simplest  way

Comment: I don’t disagree! Good solution you provided with JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Ok two options you can either

1. Adjust the current button's onClick event from
   `<button onClick="addNewElement('receivers', <?php $receiverNumber ?>, 'R')">+</button>`;

***to*** `<button onClick="((e) => {e.preventDefault(); addNewElement('receivers', <?php $receiverNumber ?>, 'R')} )()">+</button>`

2. If you have your HTML and JS in the same file you can do it like this

`const addElementButton = document.querySelector('.addElementButton');
const recieverNumber = <?php echo $receiverNumber; ?>;
addElementButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => { e.preventDefault(); addNewElement('receivers', recieverNumber, 'R') })`

Comment: This works but makes it a little cluttered...using pure JS and HTML edits for this issue makes more sense in terms of performance and reliability.

Comment: Maybe, its just how I'd usually handle something like this. The <button type="button"></button> is new to me never seen it till just now, so thanks for that.

Comment: No problem - a lot of times with these forms issues arise because of lack of defining elements, like the button in this case.  Usually a simple fix!